# Aggregating by median value in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to take the median value for each cobrand_id in the following query:

```
select cobrand_id, median(xsum) from tmp_median
group by cobrand_id;
```

I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2, which is not recognizing the database function 'median.'  Is there a workaround?

Comment: This? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median Page says you need 8.4 minimum

Comment: I know, which is why I ask for any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  Assuming this is a numeric value:

```
select cobrand_id, avg(xsum) as median
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cobrand_id order by xsum) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by cobrand_id) as cnt
      from tmp_median m
     ) m
where 2*seqnum in (cnt, cnt + 1, cnt + 2)
group by cobrand_id;
```

The `where` clause filters the rows to either 1 or 2 for each `cobrand_id` (note the `2*`), so this works for both even and odd numbers in each partition.  The average of these values is then the median.