# How to calculate median in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table in my postgress server:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   gen_info_reporting_period         DATE  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,gen_info_data_type                INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2 INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4 INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5 INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-06-01',1,410,4,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-10-01',1,403,4,5);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-05-01',1,412,5,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-06-01',2,411,4,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2019-04-01',2,415,6,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-06-01',1,438,6,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-10-01',1,401,5,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-05-01',1,443,4,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2019-04-01',2,405,4,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-06-01',1,415,6,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-10-01',1,439,6,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-05-01',1,444,5,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-06-01',2,450,4,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2019-04-01',2,432,4,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-06-01',1,415,6,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-10-01',1,439,6,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-05-01',1,444,5,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-06-01',2,450,4,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2019-04-01',2,432,4,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-06-01',1,441,4,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-10-01',1,433,4,5);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-05-01',1,432,6,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-06-01',2,424,5,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2019-04-01',2,449,4,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-06-01',1,432,4,5);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-05-01',1,434,6,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-06-01',2,443,4,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2019-04-01',2,447,6,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-06-01',1,417,5,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-10-01',1,412,4,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-05-01',1,449,6,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-06-01',2,440,6,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2019-04-01',2,441,6,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-10-01',1,425,6,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-06-01',2,418,6,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-06-01',2,414,6,6);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-10-01',1,437,5,3);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2017-06-01',1,449,5,4);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2018-05-01',1,417,6,2);
INSERT INTO mytable(gen_info_reporting_period,gen_info_data_type,data_elements_newborn_births_de_2,data_elements_newborn_births_de_4,data_elements_newborn_births_de_5) VALUES ('2019-04-01',2,435,6,2);
```

and would like to run a query that gives me the medians as shown in the query below:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT gen_info_reporting_period,
              gen_info_data_type,
              sum(ind1.INDICATOR1) AS INDICATOR,
              district,
              region,
              overall_median,
              baseline_median
       FROM
         (SELECT gen_info_reporting_period,
                 gen_info_data_type,
                 (data_elements_newborn_births_de_2 :: NUMERIC) + (data_elements_newborn_births_de_4 :: NUMERIC) + (data_elements_newborn_births_de_5 :: NUMERIC) AS INDICATOR1,
                 Split_part (qed.nuis_region_district_label, ',', 2) AS district,
                 Split_part (qed.nuis_region_district_label, ',', 1) AS region,

            (SELECT Percentile_cont(0.5) within GROUP (ORDER BY INDICATOR)
             FROM
               (SELECT gen_info_reporting_period,
                       sum(INDICATOR)
                INDICATOR
                FROM
                  (SELECT gen_info_reporting_period,
                          (data_elements_newborn_births_de_2 :: NUMERIC) + (data_elements_newborn_births_de_4 :: NUMERIC) + (data_elements_newborn_births_de_5 :: NUMERIC) AS
                   INDICATOR
                   FROM qed) AS mb1 GROUP  BY gen_info_reporting_period) AS poo) AS baseline_median,

            (SELECT Percentile_cont(0.5) within GROUP (ORDER BY INDICATOR)
             FROM
               (SELECT gen_info_reporting_period,
                       sum(INDICATOR)
                INDICATOR
                FROM
                  (SELECT gen_info_reporting_period,
                          (data_elements_newborn_births_de_2 :: NUMERIC) + (data_elements_newborn_births_de_4 :: NUMERIC) + (data_elements_newborn_births_de_5 :: NUMERIC) AS
                   INDICATOR
                   FROM qed) AS om1 GROUP  BY gen_info_reporting_period) AS foo) AS overall_median,
                 Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY qed.nuis_facility_id,
                                                 gen_info_data_type
                                    ORDER BY gen_info_reporting_period) AS row_num
          FROM qed) ind1 GROUP  BY gen_info_reporting_period,
                                   gen_info_data_type,
                                   region,
                                   district,
                                   overall_median,
                                   baseline_median) AS moo
```

In theory, I am calculating a column `indicator` which is a sum of `data_elements_newborn_births_de_2`,`data_elements_newborn_births_de_4`,`data_elements_newborn_births_de_5`.
From the column indicator, I would like to get the median value grouped by reporting date as follows:

- Overall median = Median of all the data grouped by reporting period.
- Baseline median = Median of the data where `gen_info_data_type` = `1`.

I have already done this in Ms. Excel and the results are as in the image below;

[image]

My query gives me different results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregating by median value in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527860/aggregating-by-median-value-in-sql)

Comment: Hint:  `percentile_cont()` or `percentile_disc()`:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff the numbers am getting with `percentile_cont()` are off from the actual excel values. Its in the query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland let me try the link you shared. Thanks

Comment: `percentile_cont` interpolates a value if there is a even number of rows. Perhaps you want `percentile_disc`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I started with `percentile_disc` and still got same values.

Comment: Have you considered using CTEs to make your SQL easier to read?